# Failure of #include<string>?

Tags: syntax

I am using the following code for a class project, but for some reason the #include string is not working, and the compiler is flagging every declaration using string.  What did I do wrong?

```
#ifndef MEMORY_H
#define MEMORY_H
#include <string>
class Memory
{
private:
    string mem[1000];
public:
Memory()
{
    for each(string s in mem)
    {
        s = "nop";
    }
};
string get(int loc)
{
    return mem[loc];
};
void set(int loc, string input)
{
    mem[loc] = input;
}
};
#endif
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include the string header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103169/how-do-i-include-the-string-header)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this after your include statement:
`using namespace std;`

Comment: Okay, got it now.  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

string is part of the std namespace, instead of string, you need:

```
std::string
```

For more on namespaces go [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cb46ksf.aspx).

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for the assist. :)