# (c++) What do I need to include in header file of a new class

Tags: c++, string, header

I'm curious about something when creating a new class in c++.

In my main.cpp I have both of these:

```
#include <iostream> 
#incude <string>
```

However, in the header file of my other class, FeedInfo.h, what do I need to include to be able to use strings there as well?

For example, If I want to create a string in my .h:

```
std::string feed;
```

This code will successfully compile when I only use `#include <iostream>` OR when i only use `#include <string>` -- or when I use both, of course.

This confused me because in main.cpp I have to use both - but in .h file I only need one of them - so which one do I include?

Thank you.

Comment: You should look at some documentation. `::std::string` is defined in `<string>`. Even though it can be included in some other headers (such as`<iostream>`) you can not rely on such behavior.

Comment: If you use `std::string` then include `<string>` and if you use `std::cout` then include `<iostream>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some implementations the `<iostream>` header includes the `<string>` header so you are relying on a *free ride*. That should be avoided and you should **explicitly** include the `<string>` header when working with [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) type. For example this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::string s = "Hello World!";
   std::cout << s;
}
```

compiles [when using g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9f4f987751f7597), it does not compile when using Visual C++. So you should use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
   std::string s = "Hello World!";
   std::cout << s;
}
```

In short, if you need a `std::string` - include the `<string>` header where appropriate, if you want to send data to standard output use `<iostream>`. Here is a breakdown when using headers and source files:

**myclass.h:**

```
#ifndef MY_CLASS_H
#define MY_CLASS_H

#include <string>
 // your code

#endif
```

**myclass.cpp:**

```
#include "myclass.h"
// include other headers as needed
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "myclass.h"
//your code
```

Also take a look at this question titled:
[How do I include the string header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103169/how-do-i-include-the-string-header)

Comment: I see. So I use <iostream> to be able to access stuff such as std::cout, and <string> to directly include strings. Thank you.